# Netcore Socket Server Not Closing

Tags: c#, sockets, .net-core, tcpserver

Hi All I'm developing a quite simple Socket Server on .NetCore. This server must allow multiple clients and start reading from them while it's not canceled.

This is the code of it:

```
public class ClientHandler
    {
        public ClientHandler(Socket workSocket, int bufferSize)
        {
            WorkSocket = workSocket;
            BufferSize = bufferSize;
            receiveBuffer = new byte[BufferSize];
            currentBuffer = new byte[0];
        }

        public Socket WorkSocket { get; }
        // Size of receive buffer.
        public int BufferSize { get; }
        // Receive buffer.
        public byte[] receiveBuffer { get; set; }
        // Received data.
        public byte[] currentBuffer { get; set; }
    }


    public class MyServer
    {
        public MyServer(string ipAddress, int port,
            IProtocolParser parser, CancellationToken token, ILogger logger)
        {
            _ipAddress = ipAddress;
            _port = port;
            InternalCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            _token = InternalCts.Token;
            _parser = parser;
            _logger = logger.ForContext(GetType());
        }

        private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
        private readonly IProtocolParser _parser;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly int _port;
        private readonly string _ipAddress;
        private readonly CancellationToken _token;
        private readonly ManualResetEvent _allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        private CancellationTokenSource InternalCts { get; set; }        
        private Socket Server { get; set; }        

        public void Start()
        {
            try
            {
                var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(_ipAddress);
                var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, _port);

                _logger.Debug("Creating Socket Server On {ipAddress}:{port}", _ipAddress, _port);
                Server = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                Server.Bind(endpoint);
                Server.Listen(10);                                

                while(!_token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    _allDone.Reset();
                    _logger.Debug("Waiting For Client");
                    Server.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, Server);
                    _logger.Debug("Waiting One!");
                    _allDone.WaitOne();
                    _logger.Debug("Begin Accept Finished");
                }

                _logger.Debug("Task Finished!");
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.Error("error");
            }
        }

        private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            // Signal the main thread to continue.
            _allDone.Set();

            // Get the socket that handles the client request.
            var listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            var handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

            // Create the state object.
            var client = new ClientHandler(handler, BUFFER_SIZE);
            handler.BeginReceive(client.receiveBuffer, 0, client.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), client);
        }

        private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
            // from the asynchronous state object.
            var client = (ClientHandler)ar.AsyncState;
            var handler = client.WorkSocket;

            // Read data from the client socket. 
            var bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                client.currentBuffer = ArrayExtensions.Combine(
                    client.currentBuffer, client.receiveBuffer.SubArray(0, bytesRead));

                var (message, newBuffer) = _parser.UnpackMessage(client.currentBuffer);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
                {
                    _logger.Debug("New Message Received: {message}", message);
                }

                client.currentBuffer = newBuffer;
            }

            if (!_token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // Not all data received. Get more.
                handler.BeginReceive(client.receiveBuffer, 0, client.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), client);
            }
        }

        public void Stop()
        {            
            InternalCts.Cancel();            
            _logger.Debug("Stopping Server...");
            _logger.Debug("Closing Socket...");
            Server.Close();
            _allDone.Set();
            _logger.Debug("Socket Closed!");
        }
    }
```

And this is the main program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var parser = new VenomOEMProtocolParser();
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .Enrich.WithThreadId()
                .WriteTo.Console().CreateLogger();

            var venomOem = new VenomOEM("192.168.0.107", 100, parser, cts.Token, logger);

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += (s, e) =>
            {
                venomOem.Stop();
            };

            Console.CancelKeyPress += delegate
            {
                venomOem.Stop();
            };

            try
            {
                venomOem.Start();
                logger.Debug("FINISHED!");
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException oce)
            {
                logger.Debug(oce, "Operation Canceled Exception");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                logger.Error(e, "Unexpected Exception!");
            }
        }
```

As you can see I start the sever and stop it when Ctrl+C keys are pressed on the console app and the stop method is excecuted but somehow the application freezes and doesn't close. I think that it's something related to the reset events but cannot find the problem.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: First pass: You are calling `_allDone.Set();` too early in `AcceptCallback`. Should move it to after `var handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);`

Comment: Second Pass: You are waiting on  `handler.BeginReceive` and this has no cancellation support. Closing the server will not close these connections. You should keep track of the client sockets (ClientHandler instances, actually) and close these Sockets either forcibly or by communicating to clients the premature server shut-down.

Comment: @OguzOzgul thanks for the advices! The freezze occurs when no client has connected yet. Really annoying issue.